# Which distributions can be combined linearly, assuming they are independent?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent distributions.

I want a list of the distributions that can be combined linearly.

For example, if $X\sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and 
$Y\sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $Z= X + Y$, then $Z\sim \text{Poisson}(2\lambda)$

What are the distributions for which this is true?

Useful Link:

http://www.randomservices.org/random/special/Divisible.html

Comment: I believe you also want to assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Good point! Sorry, I'll add that

Comment: You use the phrase "combined linearly".  In "$Z=X+Y$", you're simply _adding_ two things.  "Linear combination" is often construed to mean taking things like $Z=aX+bY$, where $a$ and $b$ are scalars (which in this context mean $a$ and $b$ are not random).  If you do that with $a$ and $b$ not equal to $1$, then the family of Poisson distributions is not closed under this operation. If you just mean "added" rather than "combined linearly", maybe you should rephrase that. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

There is a 4-parameter family of these called [stable distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution).

The question states that distributions (of some type) can be "combined linearly". That condition excludes the binomial and Poisson distributions, which are only closed under taking sums of independent distributions from the family.  If $X$ is binomial or Poisson, then $2X$ is not.

If you only want the sum of independent distributions and not general linear combinations, there are non-stable (in fact non-divisible) distribution families closed under independent sum as explained in Michael Hardy's answer.

Comment: No: The family of Poisson distributions has this property although it is not a location-scale family.  Many families of distributions with this property are not location-scale families. $\qquad$

Comment: The question specified that the distributions "can be combined linearly" while staying in the same family.  Binomial/Poisson are closed only under independent sums (with all coefficients 1) from the family.

Comment: In case SE did not ping you sans @ notice.   Is there anything other than stable distributions when the condition is closure under linear combinations with non-negative real coefficients? @MichaelHardy

Comment: I'm not sure, but the question mentioned Poisson distributions as an example, so it's not clear that non-negative real coefficients were considered. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Here you're looking not for individual distributions, but for families of distributions.  Suppose $X$ is a real-valued random variable with any distribution at all and $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ are independent copies of $X$.  Then the distributions of $X_1$, $X_1+X_2$, $X_1+X_2+X_3$, has the property in question, so it's quite a large class of families of distributions.

Such a family of distributions need not be infinitely divisible.  For example suppose consider the family of binomial distributions with parameters $n$ and $p$, for $n\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ for fixed $p$.  That has just the property you've specified but is not infinitely divisible.

Nor need they be stable distributions: the Poisson and binomial families are not stable.  (Stable distributions are those for which the distributions of $X_1,\   X_1+X_2,\  X_1+X_2+X_3,\  \ldots$ differ only in location and scale.  The Poisson and binomial families are not stable in that sense.